# How to use Functional Endpoints in Spring WebFlux?

Tags: spring, kotlin, spring-webflux

I'm new to functional endpoints in Spring WebFlux and I'm having trouble implementing them in a simple application. I'm using Spring WebFlux v3.1.3 and Spring 6

**RouterConfig.kt**

```
@Configuration
class RoutingConfiguration {
    @Bean
    fun monoRouterFunction(userHandler: UserHandler): RouterFunction<ServerResponse?> {
        return route(GET("/{user}").and(accept(APPLICATION_JSON))) { 
        request: ServerRequest? ->
            userHandler.getUser(
                request
            )
        }
            .andRoute(GET("/{user}/customers").and(accept(APPLICATION_JSON))) { 
        request: ServerRequest? ->
                userHandler.getUserCustomers(
                    request
                )
            }
            .andRoute(DELETE("/{user}").and(accept(APPLICATION_JSON))) { 
        request: ServerRequest? ->
                userHandler.deleteUser(
                    request
                )
            }
    }
}

@Component
class UserHandler {
    fun getUser(request: ServerRequest?): Mono<ServerResponse> {
        return ServerResponse.ok().body(fromValue(Test()))
    }

    fun getUserCustomers(request: ServerRequest?): Mono<ServerResponse> {
        return ServerResponse.ok().body(fromValue(Test()))
    }

    fun deleteUser(request: ServerRequest?): Mono<ServerResponse?> {
        return ServerResponse.ok().body(fromValue(Test()))
    }
}
```

When I try hitting the endpoint using `http://localhost:8080/test`, the response is

```
{
    "timestamp": "2023-09-16T09:14:45.812+00:00",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "path": "/test"
}
```

Is it because spring isn't registering the endpoints as beans?

Comment: are you also sanding an `ACCEPT`header? we can't tell that much if you dont also provide debug logs.